# RxJava always emit default in Observable flatMap

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have a complex API polling as follows:

- The api `"status"` can be either `"PENDING", "FAILED", or "SUCCESSFUL"`
- I should keep pooling as long as the API returns `"SUCCESSFUL"` or `"FAILED"`
- In the case of `"SUCCESSFUL"` I should call another API to get some additional data

My implementation is as follows

```
private fun pollApi(): Observable<Response> {
    return Observable.interval(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .startWith(0L)
        .flatMap {
            api.getData()
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .toObservable()
        }
}

override fun pollForPaymentState(): Observable<MyState> {
    return pollApi()
        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
        .takeUntil {
            val status = it.status
            (status == "SUCCESSFUL") || (status == "FAILED")
        }
        .flatMap { response ->
            when (response.status) {
                "FAILED" -> {
                    Observable.just(MyState.Error)
                }
                "SUCCESSFUL" -> {
                    // fetch additional data
                    getAdditionalData()
                        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                        .map { additionalDataResponse ->
                            MyState.Success(additionalDataResponse.data)
                        }
                        .toObservable()
                }
                else -> Observable.never()
            }
        }
}

sealed class MyState {
    object Error: MyState()
    data class Success(additionalData: String): MyState()
}
```

This works fine as long as the status is either "PENDING" or "SUCCESSFUL".

But when the status becomes `"FAILED"`, after running `Observable.just(MyState.Error)`, the `flatMap` immediately run the `else` statement and doesn't return any value because of `Observable.never()`.

So when the status is `"FAILED"` instead of `Observable.just(MyState.Error)` being returned, `Observable.never()` is returned.

Comment: What your code does is poll as long as the status is NOT "SUCCESSFUL" or "FAILED". Once either of these statuses has been reached, the `takeUntil` will stop mirroring the source Observable (`pollApi`). So it will poll as long as the payment status is pending and once that's no longer the case either flatmap to an error or the other call. That said the observations you post in the question, don't make sense. The only explanations for that behavior would be if the getApi function returns different values for the states. Can you post the `getData()` function?

Comment: I honestly think your requirements don't make sense. You want to poll as long as the payment is pending and once it's successful or failed you want to stop polling as those states must be final states. This is also what your code does. If the failed state doesn't return an error, `getData()` might return a different failure status (you should use enums instead of strings).